# Helpless error in Windows Phone Unit Test output

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

Under Visual Studio express 2012 update 4 I have created windows phone app, for which i added Windows Phone unit test App. When I try to run the tests, `Tests` output windows shows following error:

```
------ Run test started ------
Failed to import IDeployService. Cannot proceed with xap deployment. This failure can be observed if the component model cache (typically located in %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\[version]\ComponentModelCache) is not up-to-date.  To come out of this error, close all instances of visual studio, delete the component model cache folder and try again.
Unit tests in source D:\projekty\PhoneApp3\TestApp1\Bin\x86\Debug\TestApp1.dll cannot be run. Please create a Windows Store or Windows Phone Unit Test project.
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:00,0009998) ==========
```

Deleting of `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\[version]\ComponentModelCache` does not help

EDIT:
If I open the same solution in VS 2013 Express for Windows I can successfully run those tests

Comment: Lovely error, I should frame it on my wall :D

Comment: Maybe try closing VS, deleting that folder, deleting your `/bin` and `/obj` folders, rebuilding, and trying again?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a side-by-side installation of VS21012+Update4 and VS2013 Express?

Maybe you could try repairing your VS2012 installation from "Programs & Features" in control panel and see if that resolves this issue?